# Unable to set up a static ip ethernet connection in Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop, what is normally put for netmask and gateway?

Tags: networking, 20.04, static-ip

I have a static ip address and have been unable to connect to the internet through ethernet since upgrading from 18.04. I have the following information regarding the static ip configuration:

```
Static IP: 120.237.28.48

Network:   120.237.28.0/24 (and so I have 0-255 for the last entry?)
```

but have no idea how to map these into the connecting settings menu in 20.04:

[image]

For example, the netmask, gateway, and the DNS server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a adrress+mask of 120.237.28.0/24 (the `/24` is [CIDR notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing#CIDR_notation) is the same as a mask of `255.255.255.0`) means that the computers connected to the same LAN have addresses in the range 120.237.28.0 .. 120.237.28.255. Your computer can talk directly to these.

To communicate with computers outside this range, your computer talks to the gateway, which is another system with a connection in your local LAN and a connection to the outer world (it has an address in each). The gateway address that you need is the address in your LAN, usually at either end of the range: 120.237.28.0 or 120.237.28.254 (the final address of the range is reserved as a "broadcast" address).

The DNS can be any server that answers to DNS requests, you can use the OpenDNS ones: 208.67.222.222 or 208.67.220.220. A DNS server provided by your organization can also resolve names that are useful in everyday' life, such as printers, or local servers.

I assume that this is for a server; in general an individual's system doesn't get a public address like yours (which means that the computer can be accessed from the internet), one connects to a private network (`192.168.*.*` or `10.*.*.*`) and the public address is borne by the router that connects that local network to the internet.

Comment: this is a wonderful answer, thank you so much!

Comment: you should specify the actual subnet mask(or cidr abbreviation) so that an uninformed reader can better discern what to enter as the netmask on a GUI like that.

Comment: I agree with @WU-TANG. You should specify in the answer that the netmask field should be filled as `255.255.255.0` in the GUI for users who are not familiar with the Internet Protocols (IP).

Comment: @user68186 yes either that and/or /24... in the case of what the field currently accepts, 24.